# How does one debug javascript for a .Net Core Web app inside VS Code?

Tags: javascript, .net-core, vscode-debugger

I have yet to find a way to invoke the VS Code javascript debugger on the javascript within my .Net Core web project.

Consequently I end up debugging my C# controllers in VS Code and Javascript in Chrome.

I can find instructions for using node.js, but this project isn't using node, and I can find instructions for using it on bare webpages (which might still be relevant), but nothing for .Net Core.

When I set a breakpoint in the javascript file it shows, but as soon as I launch, the breakpoint disappears and the message says

```
No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

The launch configuration:

```
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/console.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"                
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
    },
```

It's entirely possible that my ability to debug is restricted by the use of bundleconfig, which I know is awfully obsolete but the time required to modernize it can't be justified. Especially since the Chrome debugger doesn't have an issue.